# HTML5 audio volume in Javascript (Android 2.3)

Tags: android, volume, html5-audio

```
// Standard HTML5 implementation of StartMusic.
function Html5StartMusic(music)
{
    var player = document.getElementById('musicPlayer');
    player.volume = 0.1;
    player.setAttribute('src', 'music/' + music + '.ogg');
    player.play();
}
```

Setting volume does work in PC Chrome, but not in Android 2.3 Webkit. Is there an alternative way to make it work?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've workarounded the problem, writing my own player at the application side, that supports volume control. To callback player functions I use onJsAlert() as API (onConsoleMessage() seems to be better, but I heard on some phones it's disabled).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
yourAudioElement.mute = true
```